# AndroidHttpClient and HttpGet API deprecated in Android 6.0 Marshmallow (API 23)

Tags: android, androidhttpclient, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-compatibility

Today I have updated android SDK API 23.

As soon as I have changed my project to target Android SDK API 23, I started to get an error regarding Apache's client and **AndroidHttpClient** API in eclipse. 
Apache library API can no longer be found in API 23, nonetheless to continues to be working fine with API 22 and below.

Can someone kindly suggest what the problem is behind these errors?

[image]

One more error in project

[image]

[image]

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entire Apache API was removed from SDK 23 since from SDK 22 it was already deprecated.

You can see it here: http://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/23/changes.html

You can use Retrofit or Volley to reimplement your network requests.

Answer (score 9):

To continue using the Apache HTTP APIs, you must first declare the following compile-time dependency in your build.gradle file:

```
android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

Official reference: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client